# Generalization of Borel functional calculus

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, sp.spectral-theory, functional-calculus

[Repost from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802593/generalization-of-borel-functional-calculus]

Let $A$ be a normal operator on a Hilbert space $V$. The continuous functional calculus gives an isometry $\cdot(A): \mathcal{C}(\sigma(A))\to \mathcal{B}(V)$. There is a standard way to extend this to bounded Borel-measurable functions, but working through the argument I am confused why one has to stop there -- it seems that one trivially gets quite a bit more. Since I have not seen this anywhere I assume that this is wrong, but I am not sure where this is wrong and would appreciate any help in sorting this out.

Claim: the continuous functional calculus extends to a norm 1 bounded map $\cdot(A): (\mathcal{C}(\sigma(A)))'' \to \mathcal{B}(V)$, and furthermore we can repeat this argument any number of times so that the domain is the result of taking any even number of duals of $\mathcal{C}(\sigma(A))$.

I'll just do this for the double dual -- hopefully the inductive step is clear. Fix $u,v\in V$. Then, $f\mapsto (f(A)u, v)$ defines a $\tilde F_{u,v}\in (\mathcal{C}(\sigma(A)))'$ with norm at most $\|u\| \|v\|$, and hence an $F_{u,v} \in (\mathcal{C}(\sigma(A)))'''$ with norm at most $\|u\| \|v\|$. For any $\tilde f\in (\mathcal{C}(\sigma(A)))''$, one thus obtains a sesquilinear form $u\times v\mapsto F_{u,v}(\tilde f)$ which defines a bounded operator $\tilde f(A)$ with norm at most $\|\tilde f\|$. Also, $\tilde f(A)$ depends linearly on $\tilde f$.

I believe that this proves the claim. But, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47544/double-dual-of-the-space-c0-1 explains that the bounded Borel-measurable functions are contained strictly in $(\mathcal{C}(\sigma(A)))''$. So, the same argument that is usually used for bounded Borel-measurable functions seems to get much more.

Finally, Lax's Functional Analysis book on page 82 asserts that for any compact metric space $Q$, $(\mathcal{C}(Q))''$ is the space of bounded Borel-measurable functions on $Q$, which clearly disagrees with the linked post above. Is Lax simply wrong? He doesn't prove this result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your argument looks correct to me. It’s just there’s not much point in doing this - Borel functional calculus already gives you everything in the von Neumann algebra generated by the range of the continuous functional calculus. Extending this to $C(\sigma(A))’’$ gives you the same range and $C(\sigma(A))’’$ is in most cases an intractable object that there’s no point bothering with it.

Comment: I would assume Lax is either wrong or maybe there’s a misunderstanding. $C(Q)’’$ is always a von Neumann algebra but the bounded Borel functions on $Q$ nearly never form one. (Also, $l^\infty(Q)$ is a quotient of $C(Q)’’$, which in most cases is larger than bounded Borel functions.)

Comment: I should clarify that when I say “Borel functional calculus already gives you everything in the von Neumann algebra generated by the range of the continuous functional calculus” I’m assuming your Hilbert space is separable.

Comment: But does it preserve products, usually the point of a functional calculus?

Comment: OK, thanks to both of you! So, for any $n\ge 0$ there is a norm 1 map from the $2n$-fold dual of $\mathcal{C}(\sigma(A))$ to the enveloping von Neumann algebra $W$, but for separable Hilbert spaces the Borel calculus already got you all of $W$ and so this doesn't get you anything new. For non-separable spaces, is it then possible that as $n$ increases you get more and more of $W$, and perhaps $W$ is the union of the ranges of these maps? And I agree with terceira -- it doesn't make sense to multiply general elements of these spaces, so that is a limitation of this.

Comment: In order to deal with the issue raised by terceira (and the related issue of being able to take adjoints): could one get something bigger in the non-separable case by considering universally measurable functions instead of Borel-measurable ones? After all, universally measurable functions should be integrable for any Borel measure, right? After all, the integral doesn't care about measure 0 things.